# Почему не работает скрипт для метода execute VK API?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, vkscript

Имеем PHP скрипт для VK API. Скрипт создает запись в открытых группах ВК (метод wall.post) методом execute, т. е. один скрипт должен создавать записи сразу в нескольких сообществах.

```
<?php
$token = file_get_contents('token.txt');

$code = 'var params = {
  "message": "test",
  "from_group": 0,
};
var out = { "result": [] };

params.owner_id = -84832628; 
out.result.push( API.wall.post(data));

params.owner_id = -154893317; 
out.result.push( API.wall.post(data));

params.owner_id = -39257424;
out.result.push( API.wall.post(data));

return out;';

$url = sprintf('https://api.vk.com/method/execute?');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $ch, array (
  CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
  CURLOPT_POST           => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
    "code"         => $code,
    "access_token" => $token,
    "v"            => '5.80',
  ),
));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if(!$result){
  printf('Ошибка. Пост не опубликован!');
  exit;
}

$data = json_decode($result);
if(!$data){
  printf('ВК вернул не json!');
  exit; 
}

if($data->error || !$data->response){
  printf('ВК вернул ошибку %s', json_encode($data->error));
  exit; 
}

$response = $data->response;

foreach($response as $wall_post_result) {
  echo 'post_id: ' . $wall_post_result->post_id . PHP_EOL;
}
```

При выполнении вернул ошибку:

> ВК вернул ошибку {"error_code":12,"error_msg":"Unable to compile code:
>   undefined identifier 'data' in line
>   8","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"execute"},{"key":"code","value":"var
>   params = {\r\n \"message\": \"test\",\r\n \"from_group\":
>   0,\r\n};\r\nvar out = { \"result\": [] };\r\n\r\nparams.owner_id =
>   -84832628; \r\nout.result.push( API.wall.post(data));\r\n\r\nparams.owner_id = -154893317;
>   \r\nout.result.push( API.wall.post(data));\r\n\r\nparams.owner_id =
>   -39257424;\r\nout.result.push( API.wall.post(data));\r\n\r\nreturn out;"},{"key":"v","value":"5.80"}]}

Большая просьба подсказать что и в каком месте делаю не правильно. 
Заранее благодарю за внимание!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в коде не определена переменная `data` в строке `API.wall.post(data);`, вам стоит лишь заменить `data` на `params` и все будет работать.

Получится следующий `execute` код:

```
var params = {
  "message": "test",
  "from_group": 0,
};

var out = { "result": [] };

params.owner_id = -84832628; 
out.result.push(API.wall.post(params));

params.owner_id = -154893317; 
out.result.push(API.wall.post(params));

params.owner_id = -39257424;
out.result.push(API.wall.post(params));

return out;
```

И результатом данного кода будет следующий ответ:

```
{
  "response": {
    "result": [{
      "post_id": 14627
    }, {
      "post_id": 6883
    }, {
      "post_id": 7239823
    }]
  }
}
```